# Fixing errors from xutility?

Tags: c++

I'm changing a vector to a list. Ive fixed all the errors except these kind:

```
Error   16  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>'   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility    2010
Error   17  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>'   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility    2010
Error   18  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>'   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility    2010
Error   19  error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &,const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::stack<_Ty,_Container> &' from 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>'   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility    2010
```

How can one fix these sorts or errors if no line number indicates which file and method is causing the error? I have no idea where the problem could be.

Is there a way to find out which statement triggers these?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it you got stacks of list iterators which are you are trying to compare using the less than operator (i.e. stack1 < stack2). However, the stack just delegate the comparison of the elements to the element's operator which doesn't exist: list iterators can't be using the less than operator. How to locate where this happens I don't know but using a different compiler might give you a better error message.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you get an "instantiation stack" (similar to a call stack) that tells you `X was instantiated from Y which was instantiated from Z ...` - at the end you'll find your code that's trying to instantiate something that can't be instantiated.